# Incorrect ID being set after ActiveRecord save

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

So I'm encountering a weird bug that is happening, but only some of the time. I can't seem to nail down anything that's causing it to happen. Basically, I have a ActiveRecord which corresponds with a table in my DB. I assign values to a object and call `save()`.

Lets say I have the following code:

```
$student = new Student();
$student->name = "Gregg";
$student->surname = "Smith";
$student->gender = "Male";
$student->save();
```

Then my `Student` active record model I have the following:

```
public function afterSave()
{
    $this->assignStudent($this->id);
}
```

`$this->id` IS not the correct ID after saving. I can see the ID in the log being `1416253` while the ID in the DB for that record is `670336`. How can something like this happen?

**UPDATE**
I've done some more investigation and it seems that $this->id is assigned by assigning the last insert id back after doing the insert. Except that it is not returning the ID for the `save()` insert, but for a insert that was done previously (The insert in question was into the `log` table). This means that the insert into the student table is, according to the system, not happening correctly (even though it is, because I can see the record in the DB).

Comment: Ok for the post update. So what does `$student-save()` returns ? (should be `true` or `false`). Have you tried to do `$student->refresh()` after the save?

Comment: @Mat `refresh` doesn't work as it basically just does a select using the ID, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how a wrong id can appear. Does the wrong id match another record of the table?

Have you tried something like this to be sure to be up to date ?

```
public function afterSave()
{
    $this->refresh();
    $this->assignStudent($this->id);
}
```

Also, the documentation states "When overriding this method, make sure you call the parent implementation so that the event is triggered" ([documentation afterSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave%28%29-detail)). So I think the correct way of writing all this may be:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    $this->refresh();
    $this->assignStudent($this->id);
}
```

Comment: I just did a update. The ID being set for the ActiveRecord is the ID for a log entry in the `log` table (It's the previous insert happening that I can see in the log and the ID lines up). I have NO idea how this is happening.